# RST,ACK is not sent by FireFox/chrome in Win10 for the closed connection to the server's SYN-ACK packets

Tags: http, tcp

I am facing a problem where [RST,ACK] is not sent in the response of SYN,ACK in WIN 10 machine. Please see my explanation below about what is happening in my system.

I am running an HTTP server on a handheld printer device. From the web browser I am sending POST/GET messages to the printer for update the FW. After FW transfer, the printer is rebooted. But the client application running on Browser will not get to know this and keep on sending SYN request using different source ports. In response to this, after printer got booted up and the SYN-ACK will be sent to all the SYN packet which has come from different ports.

In case of WIN10 (only with chrome and Firefox), there is no ACK or RST-ACK packet sent to these SYN-ACK request. While in WIN 7, we could see the RST-ACK is sent to those SYN-ACK packets.

Let me know if any further information required.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why the RST,ACK is not sent in case of Windows 10. Actually irrespective of Windows version, the Firewall status was creating such behaviour.

If the Firewall is Enabled for the network, in cases where the SYN,ACK is received from the server from the port number whose session has closed at client side, the RST,ACK is not sent.

If the Firewall is disabled, the RST,ACK is sent.

Please let me know why such behaviour I am observing. Any reason for that?